# Resize n-dimensional array of images

Tags: python, c++, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I am working with face crops of different sizes, which are generated at inference time from a video. The number of face crops per frame can vary. Lets say I have n = 3 face crops of sizes `(127,321,3), (119,258,3), (135,127,3)`. I need to resize them in a single go to a new size `(new_w,new_h,3)`. The resizing will generally be down-sampling. What if it some of the crops require up-sampling?

I am currently using `opencv` resize function in a loop, but I need to do this in realtime `(< 10 ms)`. I tried to convert images to numpy arrays and resize them as numpy arrays but it distorts the images. I have also tried creating process pool, but it takes too many resources which I can't afford since I also have a deep learning network loaded in my memory.

```
new_w, new_h = 112, 112 #  new shape we need to resize images to
crops_batch = [[...],[...],[...]] # contains 3 images
resized_crops = [len(crops_batch),3,new_w,new_h]

for i in range(0, len(crops_batch)):
    temp_img = crops_batch[i] 
    resized_img = cv2.resize(temp_img, (new_h, new_w))
    resized_img = np.transpose(resized_img , (2,0,1)) # channels, width, height 
    resized_crops[i,:,:,:] = resized_img
```

My target is to get `resized_crops` array of shape `(n,3,new_w,new_h)` using batching, since I will have to process hundreds of crops per second. 
**Edit: ** What if all the face_crops are of same size already? How can we do the resizing in batch then?
**Edit 2: ** I am open to a solution in C++ which can help batch resize.

Comment: Looks like each image requires a different resizing, since the starting points are all different.  `cv2.resize` already uses (relatively) fast compiled code, https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize.  `numpy.resize` is not an image resizing method at all.

Comment: Can we somehow make `numpy.resize` work for images?

Comment: No, it's an entirely concept, similar only in name.  Read its docs, which explicitly says it's not suitable for images.

Comment: You need speed and yet you use Python. It seems odd. Can't you switch language?

Comment: I can. After I finalize this. I will move to C++. So you can suggest solution in C++.

Comment: The link I gave earlier shows the c++ code api for `opencv`.

Comment: @hpaulj Yes, but I will have to use it inside a loop, which I don't want.

Comment: What's the problem with loops in c++?

Comment: I can have hundreds of crops per second, which I can't resize them in less than 10-15 ms using loop. Though I haven't tried doing it in loop using C++ yet.

Comment: Did you try to change the type of your images before resizing? (using 8bits instead of floats would speed-up)
OpenCV uses IPP, since this library is written by Intel's guys, I don't think that you could expect better, even with numpy, if you have an Intel CPU.
An idea is to use "remap" instead of resize in opencv, so you can move the initialization outside of the loop and do only the interpolation inside the loop. That would be the clean.
If that's still not enough, the next step is to use the GPU.

Comment: I will try the `remap` part. Loading the data to gpu, and after resizing moving back to cpu takes significant amount of time as well.